# WinBUGS: Multiple definitions of a node

Tags: bayesian, winbugs

I want to define the local level model in Winbugs. The model is syntactically correct. But when I run, I got this error: "multiple definitions of node y[1]"

```
    model {

        for (i in 1:T)
            {epsilon[i]~dnorm(0,h)
                u[i]~dnorm(0,eta_h)}    

        a[1]<-a1    
        for (j in 2:T)
            {a[j]<-a[j-1]+u[j]}

        for (k in 1:T)
            {y[k]<-a[k]+epsilon[k]}

    h~dgamma(0.0001,0.0001)
    eta~dgamma(0.0001,0.0005)
    eta_h<-eta*h

    }

    data list(T=10, a1=0.001)
    y[]
    -0.7224571
    -0.397027213
    3.1808741
    1.952424816
    4.921476096
    5.258244747
    4.383846014
    6.055572232
    5.474320734
    0.703784047
    END
```

Can you please tell me why and how to solve this? I've searched around on the error but each has their own specific case and there's not a generic solution or explanation as to why this arises.

Answer (score 1):

There is a generic solution, namely "you've defined y[1] at least twice."

In this case, you have defined it once in your data and also in the line

```
y[k] <- ...
```